# RSS XML show itunes:image url in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, xml-namespaces

Hello I need some help getting the image URL of the itunes:image attribute from my XML rss feed. I can retrieve everything else in the array, but not 'mainimg'. The current code returns nothing for the image although it's there. Do you have any idea how I can do this, I'm looking for the HREF so I can place it inside 'img' tags.

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('http://rss.acast.com/globalpillage');
    $cnt=0;

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
    'maintitle' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'enclosure' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
    'mainimg' => $node->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')/*This is what I'm trying to call the itunes:image attribute(HREF) with*/,
    );

    ?>
    <div class="showcontent">
        <img src="<?php echo $itemRSS['image']; /*echo the itunes:image attribute(HREF)*/ ?>">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $itemRSS['link']; ?>"><?php echo $itemRSS['title']; ?></a></h2>
        <p><strong>Published</strong> <?php echo $itemRSS['date']; ?></p>

        <audio controls>
          <source src="<?php echo $itemRSS['enclosure']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>

    <?php $cnt ++; } ?>
```

Comment: `echo $href = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');`

Comment: Nailed it! Cheers dude. How do I give you credits?

Comment: He should post it as answer so you can check it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get namespace URI for prefix `itunes`
echo $ns = $s->lookupNamespaceURI('itunes');
// Get `image` tag from that namespace
echo $href = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. It throws a 500 Error when I add it to my array. How would you call the image from the itunes:image name space?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this, I could not get the comment nor the answer to work. I think the comment should have `$doc` not `$dom` to mimic the example code, but that resulted in just the image for the podcast each time, not the "items".  It looked like this:

```
echo $href = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

But when I changed to `$node` in the loop, I received the correct image:

```
echo $href = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Also, there are a few other typos I came across in the example code like storing `$item['maintitle']` but `echoing $item['title']`

I could never get the accepted answer to work.  In the end, this is what my code looked like this when I was scraping an Anchor podcast RSS feed:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('https://anchor.fm/s/xxxxxxx/podcast/rss');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'enclosure' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
        'mainimg' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')
    );  

?>
    <div class="showcontent">
        <img src="<?php echo $itemRSS['mainimg']; ?>">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $itemRSS['link']; ?>"><?php echo $itemRSS['title']; ?></a></h2>
        <p><strong>Published</strong> <?php echo $itemRSS['date']; ?></p>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="<?php echo $itemRSS['enclosure']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```